# Is this atomic implementation of fetch_mult correct?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, lock-free, atomic, stdatomic

[This site](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/atomics) explains C++11 atomics and gives an example implementation of an atomic `fetch_mult` operation that is not provided by the default `std::atomic<T>` types:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T fetch_mult(std::atomic<T>& shared, T mult){
  T oldValue= shared.load();
  // 1
  while (!shared.compare_exchange_strong(oldValue, oldValue * mult));
  return oldValue;
}

int main(){
   std::atomic<int> myInt{5};
   std::cout << myInt << std::endl;          
   fetch_mult(myInt,5);
   std::cout << myInt << std::endl;         
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding this function. If `fetch_mult` is interrupted at point `// 1` by another thread that also calls `fetch_mult`, wouldn't one of the threads deadlock since the `compare_exchange_strong` will never return `true` unless either `mult==1` or another thread sets the value back to `oldValue`?

For example (T1 and T2 being the respective threads):

- T1: `oldValue = 5;`
- T2: `oldValue = 5;`
- T2: `compare_exchange_strong` successfully sets the value to `25`
- T1: `compare_exchange_strong` never completes successfully since its `oldValue` is still `5` unless *somebody else* sets the value to `5` again

Is my understanding correct? If so, would this be a correct implementation of `fetch_mult`?

```
template <typename T>
T fetch_mult(std::atomic<T>& shared, T mult){
  while (true) {
    T oldValue = shared.load();
    if (shared.compare_exchange_strong(oldValue, oldValue * mult)) 
      return oldValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure "*starve*" would be the right word, either, though i agree that *deadlock* surely is not the right word in the strictest sense. Here, my misunderstanding regarding the semantics of `compare_exchange_strong` (see the accepted answer) lead to me thinking that one thread would continue while the other would never make any progress by being trapped in a loop that it could basically never exit. In my understanding, the problem was worse than *starvation* in that I thought that one thread would continue and the other sent into a (possibly) infinite loop. *Programming error*? ;-)

Comment: Ok, "suspected" error - after the answer, I noticed that my question and the suspected infinite wait loop was based on a misunderstanding of the semantics of the compare-exchange operations. ("Under normal circumstances, this loop cannot be exited in the absence of other threads" vs "in special cases, the thread might be starved".) But thank you for pointing out the starvation problem, even if that was not the point of the question :-)

Comment: @Eric: The related word is "livelock" if *all* threads are blocking each other from completing a full transaction and make each other keep aborting.  But fortunately if all threads are spinning on a CAS retry loop, at one thread makes progress every time.  So it's lock-free but not wait-free.  (And modulo HW / SW fairness, might starve, sure if there are other concurrent modifications.)

Comment: @Eric: on reading the question more carefully, the thing the OP is worried about is an infinite-loop bug, not a fairness problem or throughput collapse under high contention.  Agreed it's definitely not a deadlock, but I wouldn't call it "starvation", more like "forgetting to open your mouth".  (i.e. just a bug; there's no special name for it.  The other terms being thrown around do have specific technical meanings and don't apply.)

Comment: @PeterCordes exactly this - a misunderstanding of the API leading to a suspected infinite-loop bug.

Comment: Yep, you're all right. I misinterpreted the OP's question. Guess that's what happens when you try answering SA questions while waiting for code to compile. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`atomic::compare_exchange_*` loads the current value into the 'expected' parameter if the comparison fails. In your example, in step 4 T1 would fail the compare-exchange and load 25 into `oldValue`, and then would succeed on the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, somehow I completely missed the fact that the current value is loaded into the `expected` parameter if the current and expected values differ.

Comment: @anderas: This is the standard idiom for building an arbitrary atomic RMW operation out of a CAS retry loop.  Except use `compare_exchange_weak()` so it doesn't compile to a double-nested loop on targets with LL/SC as their asm building block.  Also, the first load can be `std::memory_order_relaxed`.  The CAS checks anyway so you want to make the no-contention fast path as light on barriers as possible.